# Old SQL History in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In SQL Developer, i was finding some SQL commands of previous month but not able to find that as it is showing only the records of last 4-5 days.

Is there any way to find the old SQL commands those are not displaying under SQL history tab.

Thanks.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As Oracle has documented, there is a SQL history folder and it is larger (has more SQL queries that go back about a year) than the SQL History tool bar (a couple of months).

Here is the content of my SQL History tool bar:

[image: SQL History tool bar]

With respect to the SQL history folder, release notes cite this location in Windows 7:

C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\SqlHistory

While this folder contains SQL History, it also contains: User-defined reports and user-defined snippets files (e.g. see  [3.1 Sql Developer release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/sqldev31-ea-relnotes-487612.html))
Here is my SQL History folder:

[image: My SQL History folder]

I do not see any documentation to adjust the size of either.

Comment: Saved me a few hours. Thanks.

Comment: the folder and the history toolbar are showing the same number of queries.  Sadly, not as far back as the query I'm looking for.  I've updated the limit as described in @MiguelKVidal's answer.

Answer (score 14):

You can try

**View > History SQL**

For example, look this picture:
[image]

Answer (score 10):

In SQL Developer, to change the limit go to:
`Tools -> Preferences`.

Inside this, navigate to:

```
Database –> Worksheet –> SQL History Limit
```

Change it to whatever you want. (In 4.0.1.14, the max was 999999999.)

Hope it helps.

Best regards.

Comment: Beware larger settings. Each history item gets its own XML file. Each of these files are read into memory at application startup time. Doing this for thousands of files will eventually impact performance. So be wary of what you ask for.

Comment: Hi @thatjeffsmith! Thank you for this info. Please feel free to edit it and add this information in order to improve my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think there is another option like this:

In SQL Developer> View menu:
[image: In SQL Developer> View menu]

Then, go to file option:
[image: Then, go to file option]

and you got recent file tab:
[image: and you got recent file tab]

Answer (score 0):

If your queries are still in the shared_pool, you can use `v$sql` and `v$sqlarea`. They would be flushed out regularly, but you can find them till that period of time.